Calendar permissions for swift repl
I am using swift repl on my MacOS Sonoma to test out some code and check fields in classes. However, I am unable to access my local EKEventStore or any event in it in the REPL as I get an "Access denied" error despite the terminal having full access to my calendar.
Is there any way to give the swift REPL (temporary) access to my calendar?
